# conditional range in sum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gams-math

I have a condition where I need to sum over the next 5 elements of a set.

My condition is: sum(neighbor(x)) = 1 w.r.t x, from x+1 to x+5

```
    Equation has_1_neighbor(x);
    has_1_neighbor(x).. Sum(x,x + 1,x+5,neighbor(x)) =e= 1;
```

Unfortunately since I need to have x in the domain of the equation I'm not really allowed to sum with regards to x.

Does anyone know how to implement a constraint like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alias of x, to use the set in both the sum and the equation.

The syntax to create an alias is simply:

```
Alias(x,xx);
```